# SFML - RenderWindow Runtime Errors with EVERYTHING

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sfml

For almost all of any object I've added so far (sf::Color, sf::Image, sf::Texture, etc.) to the sample code I grabbed from the SFML site, exceptions get thrown once I run it, to the accord of:

> Unhandled exception at 0x61C71B86 (sfml-system-2.dll) in gameboiss.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000074.

It's brought up in reference to the RenderWindow line for whatever reason. If I remove all lines referencing these objects, it works fines. Even if I leave only one line creating the variable (i.e. sf::Texture texture), the exception is still thrown. I've tried multiple things amongst looking at the locals/autos at debug and it doesn't seem to give much light.

I'm working on Visual Studio 2012, any help would be appreiciated. Below is the code. thanks :)

`#include <iostream>

#include "SFML/Window.hpp"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML/System.hpp"

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "game boi");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);

    //source of error
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("char\\spartapix.png");

    /*if(!hero.loadFromFile("char\\spartapix.png")){
        std::cerr << "Error: sprite not loaded.\n";
        return 1;
    }*/

    //sf::Image background;
    //if (!background.loadFromFile("background.jpg"))
    //return -1;

    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);

    sf::Vector2i pos;

    while (window.isOpen()){

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            if (event.type == sf::Event::GainedFocus)
                std::cout << "playing";
            if (event.type == sf::Event::LostFocus)
                std::cout << "notplaying\n";
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed){
                sf::Vector2i pos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                std::cout << pos.x << " " << pos.y << std::endl;
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed){
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)){

                }
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)){

                }
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape)){
                    window.close();
                }
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();       
    }

    return 0;
}
<code>`

Comment: Are you certain you have version of sfml that exactly matches your compiler?  I saw a similar issue when the versions do not match.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RetiredNinja's comment above: If it happens as soon as you create the render window, it's most likely some STL version difference (from the passed string; since `sf::String` is part of *sfml-system*), which is typically the case when you mix up versions (Visual Studio releases or Release/Debug builds).

Are you sure you've picked the [correct download from SFML's download page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.1/)? As an alternative, you could try downloading and compiling SFML from the [official repository](http://github.com/SFML/SFML.git).